# Accessing a website's table with a WinHTTPRequest in Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have written code that grabs a table from a website and pulls out each cell from that table and then drops them into an excel spreadsheet. The code works flawlessly when the website loads correctly.

The issue is the website does not play nice with internet explorer, therefore the code only executes successfully about half of the time. I could write a routine that checks to see if the website loaded successfully and repeat if it did not, However I want to see if I can get it to work with a WinHTTPRequest.

The lines below are how I access the table using internet explorer based webscraping, with the last line being how i load the table into a variable.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/12345:4:US"
IE.Visible = True

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:02:00"))

Set doc = IE.document

Set WeatherTable = doc.getElementsByClassName("twc-table")(0)
```

I can load the website in question via WinHTTPRequest using the code below.

```
Set doc = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/12345:4:US", False
    .send
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
```

However when I try and grab the table using the line below i get "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Set WeatherTable = doc.getElementByclassname("twc-table")(0)
```

Basically i need the equivalent of this line for WinHTTP webscraping.

I have looked at descending down through the html document(doc.body.all.item(1), etc) but I don't get very far before I run into errors. I have also looked at the Selenium addon, but I don't remember being able to download and install it successfully, and I am not sure if it is even still maintained for current versions of chrome / firefox.

Here is the full code that allows me to get the table via internet explorer webscraping and then drop it onto an excel spreadsheet.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub GetTable2()

Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim WeatherTable As HTMLTable
Dim WeatherTableRows As HTMLTableRow
Dim HTMLTableCell As HTMLTableCell
Dim HeaderRow As Boolean

Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ColumnCount As Long

Dim i As Long

RowCount = 1
ColumnCount = 1
HeaderRow = True

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/12345:4:US"
IE.Visible = True

'Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:02:00"))

Set doc = IE.document

Set WeatherTable = doc.getElementsByClassName("twc-table")(0)

    For Each WeatherTableRows In WeatherTable.Rows
        i = 1
        For Each HTMLTableCell In WeatherTableRows.Cells
            If HeaderRow = True Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(RowCount, ColumnCount).Value = HTMLTableCell.innerText
                ColumnCount = ColumnCount + 1
            Else
                If i = 1 Then
                    i = i + 1
                Else
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(RowCount, ColumnCount).Value = HTMLTableCell.innerText
                    ColumnCount = ColumnCount + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next HTMLTableCell
        HeaderRow = False
    ColumnCount = 1
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Next WeatherTableRows

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an `s`. It is plural as you are getting a collection of element`s` by className.

```
Set WeatherTable = doc.getElementsByClassName("twc-table")(0)
```

Comment: Wow OK... Thank you so much for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

To make your approach slightly cleaner, you can try this way as well.

```
Sub FetchTabularData()
    Dim elem As Object, trow As Object, S$, R&, C&

    [B1:G1] = [{"Day","Description","High/Low","Precip","Wind","Humidity"}]

    With New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
        .Open "GET", "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/12345:4:US", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S

        For Each elem In .querySelector(".twc-table").getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each trow In elem.getElementsByTagName("td")
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = trow.innerText
            Next trow
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add:

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1
```